# TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance in VueJS using Vuesax table

Tags: vue.js

I'm starting to learn vue js and currently implementing a basic crud application. I successfully display 1 record in the table but having a problem when the record count is 2 or more.

I used vuesax serverside table to render the data and here's my code for the template

```
 <vs-table
                        v-model="selected"
                        pagination
                        max-items="10"
                        search
                        :data="examiner">
                        <template slot="header">
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between w-100 add-account">
                                <h3>
                                    Examiner List
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                        </template>

                        <template slot="thead">
                            <vs-th sort-key="email">
                                Fullname
                            </vs-th>
                            <vs-th sort-key="Username">
                                Address
                            </vs-th>
                            <vs-th sort-key="User Role">
                                Email
                            </vs-th>
                            <vs-th sort-key="action">
                                Action
                            </vs-th>
                        </template>

                        <template slot-scope="{data}">
                            <vs-tr :data="row" :key="indextr" v-for="(row, indextr) in data" >
                                <vs-td :data="data[indextr].firstname">
                                    {{ data[indextr].firstname }} {{ data[indextr].lastname }}
                                </vs-td>

                                <vs-td :data="data[indextr].address">
                                    {{ data[indextr].address }}
                                </vs-td>

                                <vs-td :data="data[indextr].email">
                                    {{data[indextr].email}}
                                </vs-td>

                                <vs-td>
                                    <div class="d-flex">

                                        <vs-button class="mr-1" color="primary" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                                   title="Edit Examiner"
                                                   @click="editUser(row)"
                                                   vs-type="border" size="small" icon="edit"/>

                                        <vs-button class="mr-1" color="danger" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                                   title="Delete Examiner"
                                                   vs-type="border" size="small" icon="delete"/>

                                    </div>
                                </vs-td>
                            </vs-tr>
                        </template>
                    </vs-table>
```

Here's my code for the script

```
<script>
    import axios from "../../axios";

    export default {
        name: "examiner",

        data() {
            return {
                host: window.location.host,
                edit: false,
                examiner: [],
                selected: []
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.fetchUsers()
            console.log(this.examiner)
        },
        methods: {
            fetchUsers() {
                axios.get('../api/getExaminer')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.examiner = response.data
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.log(error))
            },

            editUser(row) {
                this.edit = true;
                console.log(row)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Currently whenever I'm trying to load a data I'm receiving this error

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I've just had this issue. it appears that if the `:data` prop is null or not iterable it will show this error.

In my case, the `data` prop became at some point `null`. for you I suggest the following:

- First, use a computed value for data prop that returns an empty array in case there is an error.
- make sure that your `response.data` is really an array or iterable object